# Delete Confirmation JavaScript for HTML form

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a delete confirmation to my form button Possible JavaScript to use? This is what I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#delet").click(function(){
       if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Member?")){
      return false;
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want a confirmation box to appear when deleting the rest of the members since it only shows on the first one.

Comment: Firstly share your all code and `#delet` is represent Id... This will represent only 1 element

Comment: <a href="db/controller.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                  <button type="button" id="delet"  class="btn-xs bg-maroon margin">delete</button>
                  </a>

Comment: You need to change `id='delet'` to add **delet** in class and use `'.delet'` in selector. If possible kindly share code on fiddle. I will we help out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple delete buttons you can assign a class to them
and select them in your javascript (click handler)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
       if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Member?")){
      return false;
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

'#delete' selector selects one element whose id is 'delete'

'.delete' selector selects all elements who has class 'delete'